# recvfrom() not returning number of bytes received

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, udp

This is a very basic question (hopefully) about using recvfrom() in windows, c++.

I am implementing a very basic UDP function which sends a message, then receives a character message in return.  When I call recvfrom(), I get the appropriate message back, but the function does not return the number of bytes (characters) received.  Instead it returns 0.
snippet:

```
sendto(sock, "10000;1;Chris\0", 14, 0, 
   (struct sockaddr FAR *) &sin, sizeof(sin));

if(nchars = recvfrom(sock, buf, LINELEN, 0, NULL, NULL) < 0)
    errexit("recvfrom failed: error %d\n", GetLastError());
buf[nchars] = '\0';
```

My return message needs a null character appended to it, but nchars keeps returning as 0, making this difficult.  Any ideas why recvfrom() would not return the number of bytes received?

Comment: Surely if `recvfrom` is returning zero, you didn't actually receive anything. I very much doubt `recvfrom` is broken in such a fundamental way - after all, it's most likely what your browser is using to view this page...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the operator precedence in your if-statement.
What you want is

```
if ((nchars = recvfrom(sock, buf, LINELEN, 0, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
```

Happy facepalming, I guess. :)